# Why this Logit example randomly generating "PerfectSeparationError: Perfect separation detected, results not available"

Tags: python, statsmodels

This python code is ramdomly generating "PerfectSeparationError". This is a group a 50 random[-2 to 2] points centered [-2,2] and 50 random[-2 to 2] centered [2,2]. First 50 is assigned to 0 and the result to 1. I do not understand why this error occurs, I think points are enough separated to get a result

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy import stats
stats.chisqprob = lambda chisq, df: stats.chi2.sf(chisq, df)

N = 100
D = 2

X = np.random.randn(N,D)

# center the first 50 points at (-2,-2)
X[:50,:] = X[:50,:] - 2*np.ones((50,D))

# center the last 50 points at (2, 2)
X[50:,:] = X[50:,:] + 2*np.ones((50,D))

# labels: first 50 are 0, last 50 are 1
T = np.array([0]*50 + [1]*50)

# add a column of ones

y = pd.Series(T.tolist())
Xb = pd.concat([pd.Series(X[:,0].tolist()), pd.Series(X[:,1].tolist())], axis=1)

logit_model=sm.Logit(y,Xb)
result=logit_model.fit()
print(result.summary())
```

Whats the reason that randomy shows: "PerfectSeparationError: Perfect separation detected, results not available"?

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46780550/what-is-causing-perfectseparationerror-in-python-statsmodels-0-8

Comment: I understand the question from this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88226/how-to-describe-and-present-the-issue-of-perfect-separation?rq=1